# Give value to slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

Hi I have to say that this is not my code.. someone else did it and now i'm quite lost trying to figure out how can i give values to the three sliders.
I don't want a default value I want every slider to take it from: value="@getValueForThisSlider(o._1.getId)" as you can see in the HTML every slider has a different method, I could not find any solution to show the right value. Help please! Thanks!

**JS:**

```
$(".rating .slider").each(function () {
            $(this).empty().slider({
                range: "min",
                value: ??
                step: 0.1,
                min: 1,
                max: 10,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).parent().find(".amount").val(ui.value);
                }
            });
            $(this).parent().find(".amount").html($(this).slider("value"));
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field field-wrapper-rating" name="changes-values" id="change-values" style="display: none;">
  <div class="rating rating-price"> PriceQuality <span name="priceQuality" id="priceQuality" class="amount" value="@getPriceQuality(o._1.getId)"></span>
     <div id="slider-kwaliteit" class="slider" name="priceQuality"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="rating rating-hygiene"> Hygiene <span name="hygiene" id="hygiene" class="amount"></span>
   <div id="slider-hygiene" class="slider" name="hygiene"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="rating rating-service"> Service <span name="service" id="service" class="amount"></span>
    <div id="slider-service" class="slider" name="service" value="@getService(o._1.getId)"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `slider` element has the `value` attribute then

```
$(".rating .slider").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $amount = $this.parent().find(".amount");
    $this.empty().slider({
        range: "min",
        value: $this.attr('value'),
        step: 0.1,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $amount.val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $amount.html($this.slider("value"));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eYzQ4/)

Comment: Thanks i spend so much time on this.. at the end it was very simple!!